# Tidymodels produces different Results

Tags: machine-learning, tidyverse, tidymodels

I built eight different machine learning models back in October 2021 using Tidymodels. Back then, I carefully saved the input data, my output and my .R files. Now, when I run my codes again, I get totally different outputs. I have updated my packages since October, and the only explanation that I can think of is that there has been some updates that cause the discrepancies. O wonder if others have experienced such issues and if they have been able to resolve it.

Edit: I am using the same machine and the same random seeds.

Comment: Could this be due to the breaking change in [rsample](https://rsample.tidymodels.org/news/index.html#rsample-010) to correct how data is split? This does sound frustrating, but we have also observed changes in underlying model engine packages (which we don't control). If you have high reproducibility needs, we recommend that you use something like [renv](https://rstudio.github.io/renv/) to guarantee exact package version matches.

Comment: Thanks, @Julia Silge, each of my eight models utilizes different underlying packages. Although possible, it is unlikely that all of them made significant changes recently. It can be due to rsmaple, as it would impact all my models. Is it possible to track the history of a package versions on a machine? I want to know when, and which version of rsmaple I installed.

Answer (score 0):

Following @Julia Silge's clue, I installed an older version of the [rsample](https://rsample.tidymodels.org/news/index.html#rsample-010) package (version 0.0.9) and then I could reproduce all my results.